# Why isn't auto keyword working with initialization list of pointers to functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, auto

I've been recently trying out C++11, specifically the `auto` keyword, which turned out to be quiet interesting and useful.

However, for some reason it doesn't work with initialization list of pointers to functions.
Firstly I looked for the answer in my book and I found that "auto keyword only works for single initialization values and not for initialization lists", but when I've tried:

```
auto foo = { "bar", "bar", "bar" };
std::cout << *(foo.begin());
```

it worked just fine, but when I try to do that:

```
// bar is a simple void bar() function
auto foo = { bar, bar, bar };
```

Visual Studio compiler spits:

```
error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
```

While that works:

```
auto foo = bar;
```

Therefore I have decided to make a little trip over the internet to get more information about `std::initializer_list` and there I have learned that it's actually quite similar to `std::vector`. So, why wouldn't I try it?

```
std::vector<void (*)()> foo = { bar, bar, bar };
(*foo.begin())();
```

Work flawlessly. Since then I'm stuck and I have no idea why `auto` keyword doesn't work with initialization list of pointers to functions. Why does it have problems particularly with pointers to functions and what is most important does C++ standard say anything about it?

**EDIT**:

I've also tried the same thing using GCC and yup, it works and therefore it looks like you guys are right that MSVC compiler has a bug. I guess I'll need to wait until they fix it and in meantime I'll be simply using GCC.

Comment: What environment are you using?

Comment: @elyashiv Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop with Update 1 installed.

Comment: `An internal error has occurred in the compiler.` This points to a compiler bug. C++11 is relatively new and MSVC is still having a lot of problems implementing it. I don't know what the standard says, but it looks to me like a compiler bug or at least a not fully implemented feature.

Comment: Welcome to the sad reality. Compilers do have bugs in them - they become visible if you try to do something outside "established" scope. Man, I had so much hard time with both MSVC and g++ when working on C++ vector swizzling library.

Comment: File a bug report on [connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/). They will most likely close it as WONTFIX, but at least you'll have done your duty :)

Comment: @Peter My original explanation is incorrect, or a half-truth at best. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Praetorian thank you for spending some extra time to provide better answer! I was actually a bit surprised that you said that the elements of `foo` are references to functions as a book that I'm reading says that they are pointers, but well, it wouldn't be the first time that author of the book makes a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have should work, that's a VC++ bug. However, in the expression

```
auto foo = { bar, bar, bar };
```

the elements of `foo` are not pointers to functions, but references to functions. If you want `foo` to contain pointers to functions, you need to create it as:

```
auto foo = { &bar, &bar, &bar };
```

The difference is demonstrated by this example:

```
#include <type_traits>

void bar() {}

template<typename T>
using remove_ref_and_const = typename std::remove_const<
                                  typename std::remove_reference<T>::type
                             >::type;

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<
                    remove_ref_and_const<decltype(bar)>,
                    void()>::value, "Oops1");

    static_assert(std::is_same<
                    remove_ref_and_const<decltype(&bar)>,
                    void(*)()>::value, "Oops2");
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32f71f0f76c95b6b)

---

EDIT: The answer above isn't entirely correct. Even though there is a difference between `bar` vs. `&bar`, when you add them to an initializer list, the former will also decay into pointer to function. The following couple of `static_assert`s demonstrate this.

```
auto foo1 = { bar, bar, bar };
auto foo2 = { &bar, &bar, &bar };

static_assert(std::is_same<
                remove_ref_and_const<decltype(*foo1.begin())>,
                void(*)()>::value, "Oops3");

static_assert(std::is_same<
                remove_ref_and_const<decltype(*foo2.begin())>,
                void(*)()>::value, "Oops4");
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a50e01211970245)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is simply a bug of MS VC++. At least this code

```
auto foo = { bar, bar, bar };
```

where bar is some function is compiled successfully with GCC.

Answer (score 2):

The message

```
error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
```

shows that it's a bug in the compiler. I've just tried it in gcc 4.7.2, and the following code works nicely and prints "Hello!":

```
#include <iostream>

void bar()
{
    std::cout << "Hello!\n";
}

int main()
{
    auto foo = { bar, bar, bar };
    (*(foo.begin()))(); // prints "Hello!"
}
```